# Create IPv6 socket in Windows XP, using python

Tags: python, sockets, windows-xp, python-3.x, ipv6

The following piece of code works on Windows7 and Linux, but gives an Error in Windows XP:

```
import socket
print(socket.has_ipv6)
print("INET=",socket.AF_INET,"\nINET6=",socket.AF_INET6,"\nDGRAM=",socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s6 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #Error in XP
```

This is the output in Windows XP:

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:51:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import socket
>>> print(socket.has_ipv6)
True
>>>
>>> print("INET=",socket.AF_INET,"\nINET6=",socket.AF_INET6,"\nDGRAM=",socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
INET= 2
INET6= 23
DGRAM= 2
>>>
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s
<socket.socket object, fd=1840, family=2, type=2, proto=0>
>>>
>>>
>>> s6 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 94, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
socket.error: [Errno 10047] An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used
>>>
>>>
```

Why do i get this Error, and how can i fix this?

Comment: Did you install IPV6 support on your XP machine?

Comment: Have you installed IPv6 on your Windows XP box? See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2478747.

Comment: but `socket.has_ipv6` returns True.

Comment: Now i can send and receive Multicast and also receive Unicast, but i have a problem SENDING ipv6 Unicast. I can't ping anyone's ipv6 address. Do i have to install a routing protocol with netsh? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 needs to be installed on your machine.  [Instructions are here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2478747) (Thanks, David)